# ¿Es posible crear una aplicación de Windows dual? Que sea de escritorio y servicio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, aplicación-escritorio, net

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
¿Es posible programar una aplicación con C# para Windows que sea dual? Es decir, que sea de escritorio y un servicio.

Lo que se necesita es crear/programar un servicio de Windows pero que tenga la posibilidad o que se permita enviarle instrucciones a través de línea de comandos, no solo iniciar/parar el servicio.

Es decir, que a través de una aplicación de escritorio (linea de comandos o lo que sea) se puedan enviar instrucciones al servicio de Windows, como por ejemplo, que ejecute tal tarea o que haga tal función o cualquier operación.

Saludos.

Comment: no es posible lo que planteas, los servicio de windows no tienes interaccion con el desktop.

Answer (score 5):

No es posible lo que planteas, los servicio de windows no tienes interaccion con el desktop.

Vas a tener que crear dos proyectos en la solucion:

- uno sera el `servicio de windows` que se registrara para ejecutar en background
- el otro sera la `app winform` o `consola` que interactura con el usuario

Para comunicar ambas aplicaciones hay varias formas, usando

- `socket`, o sea el win service escuchando en un puerto el ingreso de un commando o accion que debe ejecutar
- `WCF` auto host por el propio servicio de windows, esto seria una version ams avanzada de socket ya que permite exponer funcionalidad como servivio web. La app winfor/consola consume esos servicio para ejecutar las acciones que se exponen

[Procedimiento para hospedar un servicio WCF en un servicio administrado de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service)

Comment: Otra opción es usar [ServiceController.ExecuteCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceController_ExecuteCommand_System_Int32_) para enviar los comandos y en el servicio sobreescribir [ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand?view=netframework-4.8)